# What is the difference between Report manager URL and web service URL in ssrs 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

What is the difference between Report manager URL and web service URL in ssrs 2008 r2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web Service URL page to configure or modify the URL used to access the report server.

The Report Manager URL page to configure or modify the URL used to access Report Manager.

The report server is the central component of a Reporting Services installation. It consists of a pair of core processors plus a collection of special-purpose extensions that handle authentication, data processing, rendering, and delivery operations. Processors are the hub of the report server.

Report Manager is an ASP.NET web application that provides report management/viewing capabilities for a Reporting Services instance configured in native mode.

For more information please see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188133.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181174.aspx