# My Reporting Services 2012 web service URL only shows a directory listing

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, report

I have reporting services setup on my machine. I can access http://localhost:8080/Reports and the reports manager works fine.

When I try accessing the web service URL (http://localhost:8080/TRADE) all I get is a directory listing that looks something like:

---

```
 viernes, 04 de mayo de 2018 16:35        <dir> Gestión Proveedores
 viernes, 11 de mayo de 2018 13:20        <dir> Reportes Operativos
 jueves, 19 de abril de 2018 20:36        <dir> Reportes RRHH
  lunes, 23 de abril de 2018 15:08        <dir> Reportes Sistemas
```

### Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Versión 11.0.7001.0

I would like to use the web service same as report manager

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might want to review what the difference between the two URLs is.

[What is the difference between Report manager URL and web service URL in ssrs 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523079/what-is-the-difference-between-report-manager-url-and-web-service-url-in-ssrs-20)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181174.aspx

Comment: So i have to create a Web service App and linked with my reports service?